# Challenging Question: for Expected Value of a particular probability density function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, exponential-function

I've been stuck on this for a while and it's been driving me crazy. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to find the Expected Value of the following Probability Density Functions (where E is Euler's number) for the x values shown below. For some reason I get very different values from my calculations of the expected value when applying the discrete and continuous method of calculating expected value to my data set. If you can, please give me the expected value and the expected value function, I can compare it to mine.

First PDF function: 0.348*(E^((3488.034*x)-335.553)) for 0.1<=x<=1

Second PDF function: ((19.366*x)-0.697)^-5.111 for 0.1<=x<=1

Thank you, and, once again, I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: the first pdf is $ 0.348\mathrm{e}^{3488.034x-335.553}$ and second $\left(19.366x-0.697\right)^{-5.111}$?

Comment: Why not for $ae^{bx-c}$ and $(ax-b)^{-c}$ and substitute? No wonder that it is driving you crazy.

Comment: @Chinny84, and drhab, Thanks for your replies. So I've used wolfram integration calculator online to calculate the integrals of the two functions. I'm not sure if their answer is correct but when I plug in the values and subtract (x=0.1 and x=1) to find the expected value, I get 0.06% which doesn't make sense to me because I have set the lower bound x value to 0.1

Wolfram integral calculator link is http://integrals.wolfram.com/
Another integral calculator which gives the same result as Wolfram is http://www.numberempire.com/

Comment: That's what is driving me crazy. Also, when I do a calculation of the expected value using my discrete numbers, I get approx. 0.1 as the expected value, which makes more sense even when looking visually at the PDF.

By the way, I forgot to mention that when I am integrating the function to find the expected value, I am integrating the equation: x*PDF, as per the equation for finding the expected value of a continuous distribution (just in case anyone may have missed it). This is the same equation I am integrating using Wolfram and using when substituting values for x

Answer (score 0):

What you have are not probability distributions over that support.

$$\displaystyle \int_{0.1}^1 f(x)\operatorname d x = \int_{0.1}^1 0.348\, e^{3488.034\, x-335.553}\operatorname d x \neq 1$$

So perhaps you need to either check the support, or normalise:

$$\mathsf E(X\mid X\in [0.1,1]) = \dfrac{\int_{0.1}^1 x f(x) \operatorname d x}{\int_{0.1}^1 f(x)\operatorname d x} \approx 0.9997133\ldots $$